Python subprocess doesn't see outside functions
We work on a python package. However silly it might sound, we want a node.js app to be a part of the package (it would be one of the options in CLI). To distribute it smoothly we want the package to automatically install node.js.
I tried nodejs-bin package but it seems to be old and not working anymore.
The thinking was using Python subprocess library to do this.
Node.js website says that it should be installed like this
# installs nvm (Node Version Manager)
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash

# download and install Node.js (you may need to restart the terminal)
nvm install 22

The first part is done without problems (I tried both installing it through terminal and via subprocess). But then the subprocess.run doesn't see nvm for some reason
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['nvm'])

    subprocess.run(["nvm"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1901, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvm'

The same happens even if I use shell = True
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['nvm'], shell = True)

/bin/sh: 1: nvm: not found

When I just type nvm in terminal on my Linux it works without any problems.
Even if this solution is not recommended I would like to know how subprocess works in the background and why is this not working

You can clarify the location of "nvm" in terminal (like: which nvm). Perhaps, path to it is not in PATH environment variable. And perhaps yo need to update your Python PATH  after downloading and installation "nvm" in order to allow your process to find it.

@Andrey which nvm doesn't return anything. If I run type -a nvm I am told it is a function and then the whole definition of the function (quite a lot of lines)

It is interesting where this function is located. How about subprocess.run(['source ~/.bashrc && nvm'], shell=True)

@Andrey Same result, source: not found

source is not an external program, it is a statement which runs in the shell process.

nvm is a shell function so, in this case you need to source the nvm.sh script.
For example:
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

NVMSH = Path("~/.nvm/nvm.sh").expanduser()

subprocess.run(f'/bin/bash -c "source {NVMSH} && nvm --help"', shell=True)


Reading through the install script, the nvm function is found in $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh, with $NVM_DIR set to $HOME/.nvm by default. It then checks for each of the following shell startup files in order, and adds source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh to the first one found: $PROFILE (if set), ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zprofile, ~/.zshrc.
To make it work from Python, subprocess.run('source "${NVM_DIR:-$HOME/.nvm}/nvm.sh" && nvm', shell=True) should work as expected.
